# Filtering & Summation of a List

Tags: r

I am tackling a new problem which says:
I have a list of 4 items, each belonging to one of 3 people:

```
Item  Owner Cost
1       John    6
2       Bob     5  
3       Mary   10
4       Mary   7
```

What are the combinations in which these items can be packed together granted each person's items are not packed in separate boxes.

So I am currently using the partitions package and the *listParts()* function, for example:

```
library(partitions)

listParts(4)

[1] **(1,2,3,4)**
[2] (1,2,4)(3)
[3] (1,2,3)(4)
[4] **(1,3,4)(2)**
[5] **(2,3,4)(1)**
[6] (1,4)(2,3)
[7] **(1,2)(3,4)**
[8] (1,3)(2)(4)
[9] (1,4)(2)(3)
[10] (1,2)(3)(4)
[11] (1,3)(2)(4)
[12] (2,4)(1)(3)
[13] (2,3)(1)(4)
[14] **(3,4)(1)(2)**
[15] (1)(2)(3)(4)
```

Note that I compressed the output above.

The first output means the items 1,2,3 and 4 are all packed together. The second line implies that 1,2 and 4 are packed in one parcel and item 3 packed by itself.

Although the above provides the combination logic I am looking for, I have two problems:

1. You see the bold lines (1,4,5,7,14) are the only feasible options because it falls within the constraint of Mary's items (item 3 and item 4) being packed together and not split up. How can I select or filter these list items from the full output?
2. How can I, for each 5 feasible combinations as mentioned in point 1 above, add together the cost. I think I need list indexing or something, I'm not sure how. For example if I calculate the cost for permutation [14] (3,4)(1)(2), I need to get to a cost for parcel 1 of 10+7 = 17 (cost of Mary's items), 6 for parcel 2 (cost of John's item) and 5 for parcel 3(cost of Bob's items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand how you want to calculate the cost, but I think the easiest solution for you is to first group by owner, and then make the combination.

```
plouf <- setDT(read.table(text = "Item  Owner Cost
                          1       John    6
                          2       Bob     5  
                          3       Mary   10
                          4       Mary   7",
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE))
```

You can group these two ways:

```
library(data.table)
plouf <- setDT(plouf)
reduce <- plouf[,list(Cost = sum(Cost)), by = Owner]
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
reduce <- plouf %>%
  group_by(Owner) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Cost),funs(sum))
```

Gives you

```
> reduce
   Owner Cost
1:  John    6
2:   Bob    5
3:  Mary   17
```

Then you can use setpart to do your combinations

```
plop <- setparts(3)
```

you add it to result

```
reduce <- cbind(reduce,as.data.frame(as.matrix(plop)))
> reduce
   Owner Cost V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  John    6  1  1  1  2  1
2:   Bob    5  1  2  1  1  2
3:  Mary   17  1  1  2  1  3
```

The column V1 -> v5 gives you the combinations. Then you can lapply to get the sums

```
    > lapply(paste0("V",c(1:dim(plop)[2])),function(x){ reduce[,list(cost = sum(Cost)),by = x]})
[[1]]
   V1 cost
1:  1   28

[[2]]
   V2 cost
1:  1   23
2:  2    5

[[3]]
   V3 cost
1:  1   11
2:  2   17

[[4]]
   V4 cost
1:  2    6
2:  1   22

[[5]]
   V5 cost
1:  1    6
2:  2    5
3:  3   17
```

Here first is all in the same goup, the second John and Mary in the same group 1 and bob in the second, etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, however I need to sum the costs by combination. So if the listparts permutation 1 is (1,2,3,4) then I need to sum all costs together i.e. 6+5+10+7=28. But if the combination is (1,3,4)(2) I need to sum up 6+10+7 = 23 and 5 by itself. So it's an item cost combination. I do see your point in grouping them together first though. I'd still need to sum what is within the brackets of the listParts(3). Does that make sense?

Comment: just completed the answer. Tell me if it is ok, and don't forget to accept the answer if it is

Comment: Thanks Denis, appreciate the help